# 2012 iMac RAM Upgrade

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I've just ordered the 27" iMac, which has user-upgradable RAM slots.

There are four slots, and the default configuration that ships is two 4GB modules, and two empty spaces.

**Can I fill the other two modules with 8GB chips and bring the total to 24GB?  Or, is it not possible for me to mix two 4GB modules with two 8GB modules.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can and it's quite common practice.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191

One concern might be how the memory channels are laid out, as it's generally better to have symmetrical RAM configurations to balance dual-channel access. (so you'd want each channel to be 4+8)

Comment: And how would I find that out (regarding the layout of memory channels..)?

Comment: [This page hasn't been updated yet](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423), but it will likely be one pair (e.g. the original 2x4GB) in the top slots and the other pair (e.g. 2x8GB) in the bottom slots.

Comment: Maybe a better answer: the stock RAM should come preinstalled correctly for dual channel mode, and you don't need to move it. Just add the new sticks in the open slots.

Comment: Thanks.  24GB Should be WAY more than enough.  It takes a deliberate effort to run low with 16GB in the MBP I have at work.

Comment: Hi!
My plan is to buy the new 27" iMac with minimum RAM (2x4GB) and replace it completely with 4x8GB Corsair.
Is it possible to replace ALL the slots? Or is it just possible to replace the remaining two ones?
Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can take them out easily.

Comment: OK, this might be a dumb question, but can I use 3 slots (4x2 and 8x1) ? Or do I need to use slots in multiples of 2 only? (iMac 27-inch late 2013)

Comment: That configuration will work just fine, but it won't use dual channel mode

Comment: [My experience is it’s hard to benchmark a less or more optimal layout of RAM](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402791/5472), but Apple does call for it in some but not all models explicitly. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

This sure is possible and I have just installed a pair of 8 GB modules on my iMac a few minutes ago.

By not removing the existing two modules, the new cards just plug into the vacant slots - maintaining the dual channel configuration for a total RAM size of 24 GB.